# Spring MongoDB: Querying and slicing contents of an array field directly

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework, spring-mongodb

I'd like to be able to return a subset of documents from an array field, without having to include fields of the parent document. Specifically, I have a parent document which has an array field containing objects. That array may be very large, and I want to provide a paged API to let clients access subsets of the array. I was able to accomplish this using a projection of the array, and the $slice array operator, but that still results in an object of the parent type being returned. It seems like I should be able to query and slice the contents of the array field directly but I have not found a way.

(This is not working code but is hopefully enough to convey my intent)
Given a document structured as:

```
@Document
public class Parent {
  @Id
  String id;
  String sessionId;
  List<Child> children;
}

public class Child {
  String sessionId;
  String field1;
  Integer field2;
}
```

and the following Spring Data MongoDB repository definition:

```
public interface ParentRepository extends MongoRepository<Parent, String> {

  @Query(
      value = "{'sessionId': ?#{ #id } }",
      fields = "{ 'sessionId': 1, 'children' :  { $slice: [ ?#{ #request.page * #request.size }, ?#{ #request.size } ] } }"
  )
  Optional<Parent> getChildSliceBySessionId(@Param("id") String sessionId, @Param("request") PageInfo pageRequest);
}
```

The above query definition works for getting the desired slice, but wouldn't use the sort field in PageInfo, and does not leverage any automatic support for paging in the Spring Data MongoDB API.

The [Spring MongoDB documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongodb.repositories.queries.json-based) says there is support for paging inherent with the resolution of an Aggregation pipeline, but that appears to only apply to results derived from the parent document.

```
 @Aggregation("{ $group: { _id : $lastname, names : { $addToSet : ?0 } } }")
  Slice<PersonAggregate> groupByLastnameAnd(String property, Pageable page);
```

I tried various aggregation pipelines, to try to access the child array in a way that the Spring code would page the elements of the array, but nothing I tried worked. Both unwinding the array, and the below @Aggregation resulted in a stack overflow. I also didn't didn't find a way to extract a subset of the array field without using a projection and slice, as above, in an aggregation pipeline.

```
  @Aggregation(pipeline = {
      "{ $match : { 'sessionId' : ?#{ #id} } }",
      "{ $project:  { 'children': $children} }",
      "{ $merge :  {'children'} }"
  })
Slice<Child> childSliceBySessionId(@Param("id") String sessionId, @Param("request") PageInfo pageRequest) ;
```

Is there a way in Spring MongoDb (and straight MongoDB I guess) to simply query and return elements of an array of embedded documents? This is a pretty fundamental use case, I would think, for a NoSQL DB and document model that may contain many arrays of other objects or documents.